# Conditional sum - if another cell is equal to BUY, add a number. If it is equal to SELL, subtract that number

Tags: microsoft-excel

As the title says -
I have a table which calculates the average of some buys and the number of units bought.

647 represents the sum of those entries, without adding the positions sold. But if I sell something, I need to subtract the qty from the sum, not adding it is not enough.

How can I subtract the ones with sell?

The current formula for that cell is

```
=SUMIF(O3:O13, "BUY", K3:K13)
```

but as I said, I need to subtract what was sold.

How should I edit my formula accordingly?

[image: click]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now just subtract another SUMIF:

```
=SUMIF(O3:O13, "BUY", K3:K13)-SUMIF(O3:O13, "SELL", K3:K13)
```

Comment: I have no idea how I didn't think about this. It was such an obvious answer lol. Thanks, I will accept your answer asap :)